# Is there any difference when we use expressions in html vs calling a function which uses that expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we have a component where we use ngIf to show or hide a component based on a condition. We can do that in two ways..
1) `*ngIf="a == b"......`
2) `*ngIf="checkforequivalence()".....`

Is there any difference in these implementations? My main focus is which of these is a better implementation performance wise? and will there be situations where we need one over another?

Comment: I think performance wise are almost the same, but if you use a function, you have the advantages of being able to do more complex things within it.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is blurring the lines between what is html and what is javascript. It all goes through a compiler so I seriously doubt that there will be any performance gains from doing it one way or the other, if there are, it would be fractions of milliseconds.

Really it would be up to you where you include the logic. In this case with the ngIf it would make sense to me to go with your option 1, simply because as someone comes along to read your code, it will be spelled out right there for them, and they wouldn't have to go hunting for some other function.

That being said, (to address the more general question in the title) I have encountered issues when I have tried using complex logic and functions right inside the html. I think I was trying to do something with an onClick and declaring the work right there in the html, and it didn't work. But when I wrapped it up in a function and moved it over to my javascript page, it worked fine.

**TL;DR**

Performance improvements are negligible, go with your first option for code readability and maintainability

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: in your example there is no difference.

Long answer: Usually you can say that performance of angular app depends on `digest` cycle time - all expressions in `ng-if` are evaluated each digest. Time needed to evaluate i.e. `a == b`, `a != 1 && b == c` is some small constant and it is obvious for someone reading/modifying your code, but time needed to evaluate `foo(a, b)` depends on that function. So it is good practice not to use functions in such places at all. (You, of course, meant to use functions in ng-click, ng-enter, etc. directives)